# Python using random within a loop - separated by user action

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm new to coding and started with a python course now.
I was trying to work on a word bingo game but can't seem to make it work.

```
import random
from random import randint

print "Let's play Bingo!"
print

# prompt for input
bingo = input("First enter your bingo words: ") 

# split up the sentence into a list of words
list = bingo.split()

print 
print "Okay, let's go! "

random.shuffle(list)

for choice in random.shuffle(list):
  user = raw_input()
  if user == "":
    print(choice)
    raw_input("")
    
  else:
    print "That's the end of the game ^.^"
    break

#for words in range(len(list)):
  #user = raw_input()
  #if user == "":
    #print(random.sample(list, 1))
    #raw_input("")
  #else:
    #print "That's the end of the game ^.^"
    #break
```

If i use choice in random.shuffle(list) I get a NonType error

before I used a for loop with random.sample (seen in the ## parts at the end)
That worked except in each iteration the words were still repeated.

I tried to search for similar questions but they all either had numbers or more automatic loops.

I want it so the user enters words, then each time they press enter, a new word appears from the list without repetition.
I can't seem to figure out how to get that into a loop - any help?

I tried to use random.choice and random.sample but the words still kept repeating in a for loop.
Tried shuffle and had a nonType error

Answer (score 2):

Two comments:

- Don't use `list` for variable name, it is a keyword in Python for type list
- `random.shuffle(l)` does operation in-place (i.e. after you called it, `l` will be shuffled). So, you just supply `l` into the loop. Hope this helps.

```
import random
from random import randint

print "Let's play Bingo!"
print

# prompt for input
bingo = input("First enter your bingo words: ") 

# split up the sentence into a list of words
l = bingo.split()

print 
print "Okay, let's go! "

random.shuffle(l)

for choice in l:
  user = raw_input()
  if user == "":
    print(choice)
    raw_input("")
  else:
    print "That's the end of the game ^.^"
    break
```

P.S.

Why did you decide to use Python 2? If you are new to Python it can be better to work with Python 3. It is your decision to make. FYI, [https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/#:~:text=We%20have%20decided%20that%20January,as%20soon%20as%20you%20can](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/#:%7E:text=We%20have%20decided%20that%20January,as%20soon%20as%20you%20can).

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly ^.^ Python2 was just the course I had found on Codecademy and I figured I might start at 2 and then go to Python 3, step by step. Am still doing the CS50 course as well but need more focus time for that whereas the codecademy course I can do in babysteps during my lunchbreak etc :D If you have any other suggestions for great easy beginner courses, please do let me know :D

Comment: I didn't know that Codecademy put Python 3 under pro subscription. It seems many resources (like Codecademy) that I used got partially under paywall. If you do CS50 after this, it is fine. I just wanted to warn you that Python 2 is retired technically (still some companies use it). It is just easier to transfer when you are new.